# Questions on hold - can it still be seen or answered?

Tags: support, on-hold

I'm new here and was wondering how questions get taken off hold?  I have a question that was placed on hold, perhaps because it wasn't clear enough.  I've edited it and hopefully it is clear, concise, and relevant to the community now.

But since I've edited it, it remains on hold.  Can it still be seen or answered?  I'm afraid to re-ask the question because I don't want to get downvoted out of existence like a newbie playing a MMORPG.

Comment: Your question is still visible. It can't be answered as long as it is closed. If you edit it the question will go into the reopen queue, where other users will either vote to leave it closed or reopen it. Re-asking the same question isn't a good idea, instead try to improve the current question.

Comment: Of course, the edit you do should actually fix the question so it can be reopened, otherwise you waste that chance.

Comment: When you edit your "On Hold" question for the first time, it goes to the Reopen Review Queue. Here, users can vote on reopening your question or leaving it closed. It looks like yours is still in the queue, so be patient.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question

Comment: A way to test the second question yourself would've been to bookmark the thread, log out so that you see what a user who isn't the author (you) sees, and try to view the thread.

Comment: @Scimonster : I think the first part "You performed a const_cast then a mutation on the castee" is an answer to the question "Why is that, is my program having any unsafe operations? "

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Questions that are "on hold" cannot be directly answered, but they are not deleted. They are visible in searches, and on the front page. In essence, they are *presented* just like any open question. However, before anyone can answer them, they must be improved through editing, then re-opened. Editing will put them in a review queue prompting diligent regulars to vote to re-open them.